# Can I use "gedit" through "ssh"?

Tags: ssh, gedit

I am trying to use `gedit` to see a file inside a mini-pc I connected through `ssh` but it get:

> (gedit:3864): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
>     Using the fallback 'C' locale. Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to
>   connect to server socket: No such file or directory Unable to init
>   server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> (gedit:3864): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Is there a way to see the file contents inside `gedit` in host computer?

Comment: No editor required : You can read a file with `cat file-name`. ( And you can edit a text file with e.g. sed or awk commands.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but to achieve this, you need to meet several conditions:

- allow X11 Forwarding in your SSH client (option -X or -Y if using openssh, or tick the option in SSH options if using putty for example)
- have a X server on your client PC (for example if this is running on Windows, you can use Xming https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ , or cygwin)
- allow X11 forwarding on the SSH server side (the mini-PC is I understand)

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is no x session for the TTY opened by the SSH connection.

You can specify it use the **existing** display with the `w` command and the PTY then set it as part of the session before running the application.

```
DISPLAY=:0 gedit
```